# How to create a standing up 3D text effect with Css3 transforms

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to recreate an effect like this with CSS 3D Transforms: [image: 3D text]

How do I achieve this? Here's what I've got so far

```css
body {
  perspective: 400px;
  transition: perspective 1s;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3ACizko.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: transform 1s;
  perspective: 400px;
}
.grid p {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

I thought that if I rotated the background surface 60 degrees and rotated the text -60 degrees it would cancel out the effect but apparently not?

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't achieve that effect if ``p`` is the child of ``.grid``. The reason why is because the transforms of ``p`` are then rendered onto the 3D surface of ``.grid`` so you cannot obtain the "standing" effect you're looking for that way. You'd have to make them sibling elements and make sure the paragraph displays on top of the grid using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ther solution to your problem is using transform-style: preserve-3d.

But the problem with this is that IE does not support this property

A way to make it work in IE is to use a pseudo element on the p

```css
.grid {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  perspective: 200px;
  perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
 }

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, transparent 47px, black 47px, black 50px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0px, transparent 47px, black 47px, black 50px);
  }
```

```html
<p class="grid">Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I am confident to post my own answer.

This effect can be achieved using the `transform-style` property, and setting it to `preserve-3d`. This would be set to the parent element (in this case, .grid). I also use `transform-origin:bottom` to raise the text from inside the grid. Here's the snippet:

```css
body {
  perspective: 400px;
  transition: perspective 1s;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3ACizko.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: transform 1s;
  perspective: 400px;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.grid p {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, cool! I take back my comment above, then. I was not aware of the ``transform-style`` property.

Comment: For the record, instead of using a ``translateZ`` (which requires knowledge of the height of the paragraph) you can use ``transform-origin: bottom;``. It's much easier and more general of a solution.